# Как изменить класс на чтение ключей в секции?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как изменить класс таким образом, чтобы прочитать имена ключей в секции. Необходимо прочитать ключи не указывая их имени, все ключи, что есть в секции.

Класс представленный ниже позволяет прочитать значение только известного имени ключа:

```
class IniFile
{
    const string INI_EXT = ".ini";
    string _path;
    string _exeName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, 
        string defaultValue, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);

    // Путь к файлу конфигурации
    public IniFile(string iniPath = null)
    {
        _path = new FileInfo(iniPath ?? _exeName + INI_EXT).FullName.ToString();
    }

    // Читаем ini-файл и возвращаем значение указного ключа из заданной секции
    public string Read(string key, string section = null)
    {
        var retVal = new StringBuilder(255);
        GetPrivateProfileString(section ?? _exeName, key, "", retVal, 255, _path);
        return retVal.ToString();
    }
}
```

Подключение к классу:

```
IniFile ini = new IniFile("C:\\config.ini")); // Путь к файлу конфигурации
ini.Read("key01", "GUID"); // Чтение значения ключа key01 в секции GUID
```

Файл конфигурации выглядит так:

```
[GUID]
key01=(значение)
key02=(значение)
key03=(значение)
```

Comment: [это глядели](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Reading-and-Writing-Values-85084b6a)?

Comment: Вроде там есть вариант который мне нужен, но не могу проверить его из за `string filePath`, указать путь к файлу не могу.

Comment: Как вы собираетесь читать из файла, пути к которому у вас нет?

Comment: @tym32167 Поправил, забыл про эту строчку.

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring) по `GetPrivateProfileString` написано:

> If lpKeyName is NULL, the function copies all key names in the specified section to the supplied buffer

```
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetPrivateProfileStringW",SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, string lpDefault, string lpReturnString, int nSize, string lpFilename);
static void Main(string[] args) {
    String result = new String(' ', 32000);
    GetPrivateProfileString("Test", null, "aardvark", result, 32000, "S:\\my.ini");

    List<string> stuff = new List<string>(result.Split('\0'));
    stuff.RemoveRange(stuff.Count - 2, 2);
    foreach (string s in stuff) {

        Console.WriteLine(s);

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Взял [отсюда](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/556770c1-6b83-4187-a73f-e6d177b84393/reading-all-key-in-section-in-ini-file?forum=csharpgeneral)